# Как получить по ajax новый адрес файла, который редиректится 302?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть файл на поддомене, при запросе на /файл/ происходит 302 редирект на поддомен/файл.мп3.
Такой вопрос: как получить реальный адрес файла с помощью javascript и jquery?

Answer (score 1):

[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-callhea)